# Serial Number for my PC to connect with my Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-8

Get BIOS serial number for this PC. I need the serial number for this PC in order to purchase games from my microsoft store. I have tried purchasing, however it kicked me out as my account is not linked to my PC

Comment: You can just make a Microsoft Account from Settings, User Accounts. If you have a Microsoft Account, log in and add this computer to your account.

Comment: Windows 8 activation is automatic. It’s not clear the reason you would need the serial number to log into a Microsoft Account

Answer (score 1):

To display the BIOS serial number:

1. Open command prompt
2. Type the command

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```